# bijection mapping question

Tags: real-analysis

Prove  that there exist a map $f: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ such that 
is bijective and satisfies $f(n)\geq 0$ if $n\leq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $g:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$  is understood as an enumeration or counting process, i.e., 
   $$ \mathbb{Q}_{>0} = \{q_1, q_2, \dots \}.$$
2. Think of $\mathbb{Q}_{<0}$ as $-\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$, i.e., 
   $$ \mathbb{Q}_{<0}=\{-q_1,-q_2,\dots \}.$$
3. Define $f$ as follows
   $$ f(n)=
   \begin{cases}
   -q_n & n>0\\
   0 & n=0\\
   q_n & n<0
   \end{cases}.
   $$

Answer (score 2):

Map 0 to 0.
There are denumberably many negative rationals.
Thus there is a bijection between the positive integers and the negative rationals.
Likewise there is a bijection between the negative integers and the positive rationals.
Put these three bijections together for the desired result.